# What is the music on S3E16 when Todoroki was fighting group of ninjas?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

What is the music on season 3 episode 16 of *My Hero Academia* around 20:07 when Todoroki was fighting a group of ninjas?

Answer (score 1):

It's **Kibasen**, the 13th track of *Boku no Hero Academia Season 2 Original Soundtrack*.

[YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTPJwMf6Daw)